# Will oil stains on my driveway ruin my driveway sealer?

Tags: driveway, sealer

I just finished power washing my driveway after scrubbing it with Krud Kutter oil remover solvent. The stains are better, but they aren't all the way gone.

Will the presence of these stains prevent the driveway sealer from adhering? I've given a good 5-10 min scrub to each bad spot with a deck brush and Krud Kutter concentrate. Should I go until it's spotless? I just want the sealant to stick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sealed the drive about 7 weeks ago now and it seems that the work I did cleaning the oil spots was sufficient.

My unprofessional conclusion from this experience is that if a power washer AND solvent AND 20 minutes of scrubbing doesn't get it out, it's probably a permanent part of your driveway now.

I'm pretty sure that the asphalt beneath that stain is actually imbued with the chemicals that cause the discoloration. I cleaned off what I could and the sealant stuck just fine.

Comment: I've been wondering about this.  Thank you for posting your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! I've since moved away from that house, but that spot stayed sealed up. Just make sure you give a lot of elbow grease and chemicals to especially troublesome looking areas.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Spring beckons.